# Idempotent completion, and proving the category of pre-sheaves is idempotent complete

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is there a direct proof that $\hat{C}$ is idempotent-complete ?

In [Cauchy completion in category theory](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1986__27_2_133_0.pdf), Bordeaux and Dejean give the following theorem

[image]

To prove (2), Bordeaux seemingly uses the explanation in [ncatlab on caroube enveloppe](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Karoubi+envelope) which requires to prove tha the image of any idempotent in $C$ under $y:C \to \hat{C}$ yields a split idempotent

[image]

which relies (afaiu) due to proposition  1 below on the fact that coequalizers exists in $\hat{C}$

[image]

which itself comes from $\hat{C}$ being co-complete.

Is there a more direct proof, for either assertion ("every idempotent of $\bar{C}$ splits" and likewise for $\hat{C}$)?

Comment: Any complete (resp. cocomplete) category has equalisers (resp. coequalisers), hence splits idempotents a fortiori. Is that direct enough for you?

Comment: that's his proposition 1, but I was hoping there was some more enlightening condition involving C^ specifically, without the 3 steps (it is cocomplete, it has coequalizer, it splits) which, to me, do not convey a lot of intuition, even although I know they hold.

Comment: Your original question asked about $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ but did you mean to ask about $\bar{\mathcal{C}}$??

Comment: No the question is about $\hat{C}$. The high level view is clear, just chain a few abstract nonsensical steps (cocomplete => coequalizer => splits), but I imagined there was some simple, more intuitive way to express why this well known category exhibits idempotent completion

Comment: $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ is _not_ the idempotent completion!

Comment: yes. $\bar{C}$ is the idempotent completion. $\hat{C}$ is idempotent complete. sorry for my bad English. "exhibits idempotent completion" was meant to mean "is/has the property of/ being idempotent complete" not "is the idempotent completion of C", aka the smallest etc...

Comment: I consider the argument in my first comment to be the most simple and intuitive way to see that $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ splits idempotents. If you don't believe me, try looking at the proof that the Karoubi envelope (whose objects are pairs $(C, e)$ where $e$ is an idempotent on $C$ etc.) splits idempotents!